# Create reference with API endpoint in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api

I'm trying to add a reference to a API endpoint with a WCF Web Service Reference in VS2017. Somehow any API URI I try to add there gives me errors or it just try to connect endlessly without success.
What do I do wrong? I need to make a connection with a endpoint so I can write a data exchange with it. I do have the API server adress from a swagger documentation.

Edit. I did found out that the WCF REference is working only with SOAP endpoints while I need to connect to a JSON one... So the question would be like to how connect with a JSON endpoint.

Comment: My condolences :(

Comment: You can refer to [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb48999f-cd41-49b8-ae9a-f0c8f5aebbd2/how-to-configure-a-wcf-service-to-send-and-accept-json-requests?forum=wcf).